# Plotly not updating the second color in R

Tags: r, r-plotly

I am trying to plot a basic `donut` plot in `R` using `plotly`. I then add custom colors to the plot. Now, the `first` color updates fine, but the `second` color i.e. `'rgb(255,127,80)'` doesn't.

How can I fix this?

Data

```
Value = c(50124,  9994,  9822, 13580,  5906,  7414, 16847,    59, 80550,  6824,  3111, 16756,  7702, 23034, 38058,  6729,  6951,     2,   408,
 37360, 20517, 18714,   352,     3, 42922, 30850,    21,  4667, 12220,  8762,   445,  1875,   719,   188,    26,   124,   996,    10,
    27,   304,    55, 34980,    67,     3,    25,  1012,  3588,    77,   847,    47,  1057,   924,   233,    40,     2,  2362,     3,
  1866,    16,     0,     0,     0)

Type = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A",
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A",  "A", 
"B",  "B",  "B",  "B",  "B",  "B",  "B",  "B",  "B",  "B",  "B", 
"B",  "B",  "B",  "B",  "B" "B", "B",  "B",  "B",  "B",  "B", 
"B",  "B",  "B",  "B",  "B",  "B",  "B")

df = data.frame(Type, Value)
```

Code

```
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)

color = c('rgb(0,255,255)', 'rgb(255,127,80)')

fig = df %>% plot_ly(labels = ~Type, 
                        values = ~Value,
                        #colors = c("grey50", "blue"),
                        marker = list(colors = color)
                        )
fig = fig %>% add_pie(hole = 0.6)
fig = fig %>% layout(title = "Title",  showlegend = T,
                      xaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = T),
                      yaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = T))

fig
```

Current output

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could it this way:
Note: 1. make a column in your dataframe for the colors
2. use `type=pie` with `add_pie(hole=0.4)`

```
df1 <- df %>% 
  group_by(Type) %>% 
  mutate(sum = sum(Value),
         Typecolor = ifelse(Type=="A", 'rgb(0,255,255)', 'rgb(255,127,80)'))

df1 %>% plot_ly(labels = ~Type, 
               values = ~Value,
               type = 'pie',
               textposition = "inside",
               textinfo = 'label+percent',
               hole=0.6,
               marker = list(colors = ~Typecolor)
               ) %>% add_pie(hole = 0.4)
        )
```

[image]